# How to solve summation using geometric series

Tags: statistics, summation, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

I'm trying get the value of the summation for basic queueing theory:
$$p\sum_{i=2}^∞ (i-1) ϱ^{i}$$

So we take of ϱ out:
$$p*ϱ\sum_{i=2}^∞ (i-1) ϱ^{i-1}$$

however I'm not sure what to do after that. When seeing the answer, it involves derivatives. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Does this series actually converge? What is the value range of $\rho$? One of the classic ways of dealing with power series is to differentiate them and put that in relation with the undifferentiated series from which one argument was factored out.

Comment: I don't have a value for that. It represents the rate of people entering the queue over the rate of people exiting it. The summation I'm solving represents the expected number of customers in the line.

Comment: Factor out $\varrho^2$ instead.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm pretty sure this was the form and then to use derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ p\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i-1)\rho^i=p\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\rho^{k+1}$$

Then, assuming $\vert \rho\vert<1$

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\rho^{k+1}&=&\rho^2+2\rho^3+3\rho^4+4\rho^5+\cdots\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=n}^\infty\rho^{k+1}\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\rho^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\rho^{k}\right)\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\rho^{n+1}\frac{1}{1-\rho}\right)\\
&=&\frac{1}{1-\rho}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\rho^{n+1}\\
&=&\frac{\rho^2}{1-\rho}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\rho^{n}\\
&=&\left(\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right)^2
\end{eqnarray}

So we get

$$ p\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i-1)\rho^i=p\left(\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right)^2$$

Addendum:

I am adding the following for those having difficulty following the summations.

\begin{eqnarray}
\rho^2+2\rho^3+3\rho^4+4\rho^5+\cdots&=&\rho^2+\rho^3+\rho^4+\rho^5+\cdots\\
&+&\rho^3+\rho^4+\rho^5+\rho^6+\cdots\\
&+&\rho^4+\rho^5+\rho^6+\rho^7+\cdots\\
&+&\rho^5+\rho^6+\rho^7+\rho^8+\cdots\\
&\vdots&\\
&=&\rho^2(1+\rho+\rho^2+\rho^3+\cdots)\\
&+&\rho^3(1+\rho+\rho^2+\rho^3+\cdots)\\
&+&\rho^4(1+\rho+\rho^2+\rho^3+\cdots)\\
&+&\rho^5(1+\rho+\rho^2+\rho^3+\cdots)\\
&\vdots&\\
&=&(\rho^2+\rho^3+\rho^4+\rho^5+\cdots)(1+\rho+\rho^2+\rho^3+\cdots)\\
&=&\rho^2(1+\rho+\rho^2+\rho^3+\cdots)(1+\rho+\rho^2+\rho^3+\cdots)\\
&=&\rho^2\left(\frac{1}{1-\rho}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-\rho}\right)\\
&=&\left(\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right)^2
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Interesting, I ended up getting $p * ρ * 1/(ρ-1)^2$

Comment: I am about to add some more information in case it is difficult to follow the double summation.

Comment: I am very confused about this method actually sorry!! In the solution, we basically replace everything in the summation with d/dρ (ρ^i) and so thats the geometric series so its 1/1-ρ

Comment: This is just using elementary algebra and the geometric series.

Comment: You began the summation with $i=0$ which means that you will get a $\rho^0$ term.  Were you supposed to start the summation at $i=2$ rather than $i=0$?

Comment: Yes actually you're right, it's at i=2

Comment: editing now..... my bad

Answer (score 0):

$$S=p\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i-1)\rho^i=p\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\rho^{k+1}=p\rho^2\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\rho^{k-1}=p\rho^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rho^{k} \right)'$$ $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rho^{k}=\frac{\rho }{1-\rho}=\frac{1 }{1-\rho}-1$$ $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rho^{k} \right)'=\frac{1}{(1-\rho)^2}$$ $$S=\frac{p\rho^2}{(1-\rho)^2}$$